# Reading DTL property in another DTL

Tags: sesam

I have two DTL sections. The first DTL generates a property, e.g.

```
<"equipment-service-schema:tp/12.MP.TP014": "793">
```

but the second DTL cannot read this property out.
I tried:

```
["add", "atest-TP014", "_S.equipment-service-schema:tp/12.MP.TP014"],
["add", "atest-TP014", "_S.tp/12.MP.TP014"]
```

Both DTL cannot get the value. A bug? or Is my dtl wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t use properties with `.-s` in them in path expressions.

Use the  `[“path”, “tp/12.MP.TP014", “_S.“]` function instead.